# Coco coir, how good is it?

Tags: soil

I was on amazon when I found [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M69KV51) and many product like it. It is called coco coir and from what I have read in the description on that page and a few others is that it is supposed to be airy and require less water.

But how good is it for starting seeds? I mean people have pictures of plants in this but being the shell of a coconut I don't understand how the plants get nutrients without some kind of fertilizer.

So with the above question any other tips when using this stuff would be great, I might try some of this instead of getting seed starting mix once...

Comment: Seeds carry their own nutrients in order to sprout and form their cotyledons.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Correct but what about after they run out of food from the seed?

Comment: You normally have a seed raising mix which has no or very little nutrient.   When they're large enough to grasp by the leaf, you transplant to a potting mix which has nutrients.  Don't forget that plants get 80% of the nutrients from the air.

Comment: @GrahamChiu While I knew that plants got some things from the air, I had no idea it was 80%, that is something! Once they have a leaf I do plan on translating but some people use this for there larger plants, which is why I had to ask what would happen should you just leave them in.

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/70770/what-is-the-primary-energy-source-for-sprouting-plants

Comment: @GrahamChiu well they don´t get them 80% from air directly, there is [bacteria](https://goo.gl/images/a3XDGn) that by fixation pulls the nutrients like nitrogen from the air to the soil.

Comment: @PetarPetrov I guess you'll have to argue the point with the late Nobel laureate Richard Feynman who said that trees are mostly made from air https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifk6iuLQk28

Comment: Are we talking about carbon, or N-P-K?

Comment: @PetarPetrov In General

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://www.epicgardening.com/coconut-coir/) is a good resource describing coconut coir along with it's pros and cons.  To summarize:

Pros:

- Can absorb 10 times it's weight in water
- Promotes healthy root development
- Environmentally friendly
- Deters many garden pests

Cons:

- Nutrients will need to be added
- pH may need to be controlled

Comment: It also doesn't break down as quickly as other materials like peat. I've used it for over 10 years growing cactus with excellent results.